# How to get public URL of publicly shared chatter file using REST API

Tags: rest-api, chatter

If a chatter file has been shared then SalesForce creates a URL which is public.
**How can I get that URL using REST APIs but not chatter APIs?** I want to do so because quota of chatter API calls is far less per user per hour and I want to get URLs of large number files which are public.

Comment: I haven't fully checked it yet, but can you use the [ContentDistribution](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) API and DistributionPublicUrl field? I'm not sure if it is only for Content, or it it extends to Chatter as well.

Comment: Great. If you have any content to add to the answer let me know. I.e. the SOQL query you are using. This will help the next person who encounters it.

Comment: I have used to following SOQL to get public URL of the required ContentDocument:

/services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,ContentDocumentId,DistributionPublicUrl,LastModifiedDate+FROM+ContentDistribution+WHERE+ContentDocumentId='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments, try using the [ContentDistribution](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) API and the corresponding DistributionPublicUrl field.

Use to following SOQL to get public URL of the required ContentDocument:

> /services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,ContentDocumentId,DistributionPublicUrl,‌​LastModifiedDate+FROM+ContentDistribution+WHERE+ContentDocumentId='069XXXXXXXXXXX‌​XXXX'